# How to Avoid User String Inputs in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

My program asks for an integer input and I want to make sure (error trap) that the program would print "invalid" if the user inputs a string or any other character.

I'm new to Objective-C, hope you'll understand.

```
    NSLog(@"1. Apple 2. Orange 3. Mango 4. Banana");
    NSLog(@"Choose fruit:");
    scanf("%d", &fruit);
    **if(fruit>4 || fruit<1){
        //If the user inputs any number other than the choices.
        NSLog(@"Invalid.");
    }
    else if(...){
        //if the user inputs a string or character
    }**
```

I expecting the program would print "Invalid" if it would input a character or string or anything besides the choices.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you still require an answer . Im also fairly new so anyone feel free to add . Im not sure if this is meets your exact requirements but it does what you want it to . Instead of tryign to check for each and every data type what i suggest is check if the entered value is an integer or not . If it is do something else return the error message .Take a look at the below code .

```
 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

 char str[50] = {0};                  // init all to 0
 NSLog(@"1. Apple 2. Orange 3. Mango 4. Banana");
 NSLog(@"Choose fruit:");    // print buffer
 scanf("%s",str);

// you can create an NS foundation NSString object from the str buffer
NSString *valueEntered = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];

if([valueEntered integerValue]){

    printf("do somethinng here\n");
}
else{
    printf("Not an integer\n");
}

}
```

First take the user's input as a NSString , so we can transfer it to a Integer value later onwards. The reason i have initialised it as a character is because Scanf wont allow to pass a String from what i read . So get the user's input as a character set change it to a String and check if it includes a Integer or not . IntegerValue returns the integer that the string holds if there is one , else it returns 0 .

Another method you can try is using ScanInt method in NSScanner. Issue with that is it will check if it includes a integer and return true . So something like "abc32" will also be true in that manner so probably wont be usefull for you .

Please let me know if this is what you expect as i also learnt a few things trying to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of scanf.

Having said that, using scanf for interactive input is often a recipe for confusion, so it might be a better idea to read input into a string with something like fgets and then analyze the string (possibly, but not necessarily, with sscanf).